# WebService in Java using NetBeans

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, netbeans, jax-ws

guys!

I'm kinda new to WS, as well to Java, and i wondered if you could help me.

I gotta create a WS ( Don't tell me?! ;) ) and a need to deploy it to TomCat but, i "don't" know how to do it. My WS's are meant to do some access to SP's in a database and return the results.

Simple. Its already done. Used NetBeans, developed, published on my own PC and cretead a desktop application in C# and added the WSs reference. Works great.

The thing is: the people that im going to send my WS are in other State, far away from here. I wanted to know how to do it. I saw that i can right click on the webService (The WS it self, localized inside the WebService projects folder "Web Services" generated by NetBeans) and click on "Generate and copy WSDL", get this wsdl file, send to the people that i want and they put it inside the "WebApps" folder on their TomCat Server, and whoever accesses de server can see my services.

Is that correct? If not, how can i do it?

One more thing: i created a class in java to access the database, with the connection string. There is some kinda of ".config" that i can put these information in? I didn't find that on the WebService project i created...

Thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sending WSDL will be not enough since that just defines the protocol and operations of the WS. It does not say anything about implementation. What you need to do is generate a web archive package (.war, think of it as a .jar for webapp) and send that to the customer that you are writing it for. They can then deploy it on to their server.

Comment: Yeah, man. Its the war file i want. And what about the config and database connection thing? Any idea?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by connection string, but if you created a separate class for database connection, which is part of the project and does not use Tomcat data sources (basically uses raw JDBC), then when you deploy the project to war, it should include the source code of that class as well, and so work anywhere. If you use a server data source and connect to it using JNDI, then the customer server will also need to have the data source defined. This will not be part of the war.